# How can I solve a system of linear equations in Excel

Tags: excel, matrix, least-squares, equations

I am having some trouble finding a solution for a system of equations using excel.
The system is of the form `Ax=b`, with `A` a matrix and `x` and `b` vectors. Obviously, the goal is to find x.

The system does not necessarily have the same number of equations and unknowns. An exact solution is not always possible. Therefor I want to find the best approximation, possibly using least squares.

Are there standard methods in Excel to do that?
If not, can someone provide me with a macro that does that or explain how I can write my own?

Thanks

Comment: Yes I do. Unfortunately, my supervisor told me to use excel. I am not very happy with that choice. Can I somehow run MathLab code from within Excel or vba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [the `LINEST()` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/linest-HP005209155.aspx).

Comment: This seems like the solution to my problem. However, I can't get it to work. I'll try to make it work and if it turns out okay, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) and Excel's matrix functions. Suppose there is a named range `_A` containing your matrix, and another named range `_b` containing your vector, then you can select an appropriately shaped set of cells and enter the formula:

```
=MMULT((MINVERSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(_A); _A))); MMULT(TRANSPOSE(_A); _b))
```

Remember to press Control-Shift-Enter to enter this formula as it is an array formula. It will appear with braces around it when you select the cells.